# Pivotal Greenplum - gpload issue on Windows

Tags: greenplum, hawq

When i try to execute gpload program from Windows server. It is failing due to the Error.

**Error I Get :**

```
ERROR | could not connect to database: global name 'pg' Is the Greenplum Database running on port 5432?
```

**We tried:**

1) CHECKED env variable related to greenplum database. it's defined in env variable setting.

2)Executed the batch file called "greenplum_loaders_path.bat"

**Content of YML** :  This is passing from ETL host

**Command using** gpload.py -f gpload.yml

```
VERSION: 1.0.0.1
DATABASE: prod
USER: gpadmin
HOST: hostname
PORT: 5432
GPLOAD:
   INPUT:
    - SOURCE:
         LOCAL_HOSTNAME:
           - hostname
         PORT: 8081
         FILE:
           - /serving/filename/
- COLUMNS:
           - id: bigint
           - time: timestamp

    - FORMAT: text
    - DELIMITER: ';'
    - NULL_AS: ''
   OUTPUT:
    - TABLE: schemaname.tablename
    - MODE: merge
    - MATCH_COLUMNS:
           - id
    - UPDATE_COLUMNS:
           - time
```

Any help on it would be much appreciated?

Comment: Please consider in Postgres category as well  this global user belongs to pg only. Greenplum is fork of Postgres Database.

Comment: Please provide the yml file.

Comment: @JonRoberts  I have listed the YML in question.please check once.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about the global user belongs to pg only.

Comment: I found  -when i am running gpload.py program . it utilize  global 'pg 'user from Postgres library. So , i thought it has some connection with Postgres libraries as well.

Comment: You should run gpload, not gpload.py.  The postgres libraries are shipped with Greenplum for connectivity.  It isn't the latest version of PostgreSQL either.  It is the forked version of postgres and shouldn't be confused with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Got it Jon. I will not include Postgres Tag Here onwards.  thanks for removing my confusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136975/discussion-between-sylphes-and-jon-roberts).

Comment: jon  we are running on  greenplum load tool 4.3 on windows Server. Our ETL Host is asking to run the gpload.py. can i share  ETL screenshot here ?

Comment: I already ran gpload -f test.yml  on greenplum database server (unix box) and it is  working properly. but ETL is remote server to it. and it is windows box . it is asking to run gpload.py.